Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/index.rsc vercel
Hi i'm currently learn react
after Chapter 10 (  https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/partial-prerendering )
i met the problem : "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/index.rsc'" when i push it to github repository ( https://github.com/cuonglamphu/nextjs-practice)
i get stuck with it 2 days, anyone have the solution for it, pls help me
after i try to add 2 comment and push it

the deploy fail


You can resolve this by either removing the experimental partial pre-rendering, or running pnpm i react@canary to use the canary version of next
